# Redirect http to https bitnami apache

Tags: apache, solr, https, bitnami

I want to redirect all contents of my site from http to https. I tried adding following in bitnami.config file but didn't worked.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Below is the content of bitnami.config file

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/htdocs"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

<Directory "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  Order allow,deny                          
  Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-    prefix.conf"

</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384   EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
 DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/htdocs"
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/conf/server.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/conf/server.key"

<Directory "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  Order allow,deny                          
  Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
  Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps- prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "C:/Bitnami/solr-5.3.0-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

Have I placed the rule in wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

Bitnami developer here.

If you want to redirect from http to https you have to modify the file that you mentioned above (installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf).

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Those lines need to be placed inside the default Virtual Host configuration so your bitnami.conf file is fine.

I just installed Solr in Windows and I copied the Rewrite lines to the bitnami.conf file at installdir/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf and the redirection worked fine after restarting Apache. Did you restarted the service? Please note that Apache needs to be restarted for the changes to take effect.

This [guide](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_force_HTTPS_access.3f) explains this change.

I hope it helps.

Comment: this gives me error This page isn’t working xxxx redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by adding the ReWriteRule in the wordpress-vhost.conf file. Follow the steps below if your apache installation is done using system packages.

To identify the installation type run the below command.

```
test ! -f "/opt/bitnami/common/bin/openssl" && echo "Approach A: Using system packages." || echo "Approach B: Self-contained installation."
```

follow the below steps,

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts

vim wordpress-vhost.conf
```

add the below lines in the virtualhost tag,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{enter_domain_name}/$1 [R,L]
```

restart apache

```
/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Comment: This! Why the bitnami docs don't specify to add it to the vhosts config I don't know, but this works perfectly. Its also possible to use the ${SERVER_NAME} variable instead of ${enter_domain_name}.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Wordpress**:

Please also go to `Settings -> General`

And type in your domain name like this "https://your-domain.com"

With this set, all my settings from `bitnami.conf` and `bitnami-ssl.conf` have been applied, otherwise it did not work.

[image]